# AWS S3 Server Access Logging issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, logging, bucket

If I've got enabled s3 server access logging on a bucket with versioning enabled then it doesn't log an event of deletion an object from the aws console directly (not via API). All other events are logged. How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you activate **Server access logging** or **Object-level logging**? What sub-options have you activated?

Comment: I've updated the question, it's server access logging, indeed, thanks

Comment: What you are describing should not be possible.  All bucket actions use the API, even when done through the console.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following:

- Created a bucket with Versioning activated
- Enabled Server Access Logging for the bucket
- Uploaded an object via the console
- Deleted the object via the console (which added a *Delete Marker* to the object versions)
- Waited a *long* time
- Looked through the logs

Here's what I found:

> my-bucket [13/Oct/2018:04:46:32 +0000] 124.171.18.62 arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/my-user F49F7ECC43F923B6 **BATCH.DELETE.OBJECT** config.js - 204 - - - - - - - - my-bucket [13/Oct/2018:04:46:32 +0000] 124.171.18.62 arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/my-user F49F7ECC43F923B6 **REST.POST.MULTI_OBJECT_DELETE** - "POST /my-bucket?**delete**= HTTP/1.1" 200 - 267 - 30 - "-" "S3Console/0.4, aws-internal/3 aws-sdk-java/1.11.414 Linux/4.9.124-0.1.ac.198.71.329.metal1.x86_64 OpenJDK_64-Bit_Server_VM/25.181-b13 java/1.8.0_181" -

So, it seems that deletes *are* recorded in the logs. It might just be a matter of waiting long enough, or hunting through the logs to find it.

Comment: Thank you, I will experiment with a new bucket, adding step by step all the settings from the old one. (Be sure, I'd looked through all logs, many times, waiting sometimes even a whole day before)

Comment: `REST.POST.MULTI_OBJECT_DELETE` does not appear to actually be a delete. I'm seeing it in my logs for files that are not deleted.